# Django CMS: In-Page Navigation Menu based on selected plugins

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a template in django cms which created a parallax website based on plugins I added to content placeholder. Here is my template:

```
{% extends "foundry/base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {% placeholder 'content' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

In base.html, I use {% show_menu 0 1 100 100 "foundry/menu.html" %} to generate the menu. I wanna add item to this menu based on plugins I added to content placeholder. Because show_menu called before the cms render placeholder, I cannot use NavigationNode to register my menu. If I can query the plugins which is used in the content placeholder, I can handle this menu. But Django CMS database is so complex and I can't find the query.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django CMS provides a couple of utilities to do this; you just have to dig through the source code to find them.

```
from cms.templatetags.cms_tags import _get_placeholder
from cms.utils.plugins import get_plugins

if request and request.current_page:
    placeholder = _get_placeholder(request.current_page, request.current_page,
        template_context, placeholder_name)  # placeholder_name is a string
    plugins = get_plugins(request, placeholder, request.current_page.get_template())
```

Once you have the plugins for the placeholder, you can do whatever customization you need on the menus via: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/menus.html

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still interested in doing this, here is my implementation that inserts Anchor plugins to the menu:

```
from menus.base import Modifier, NavigationNode
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
from cms.models import Page
from cms.utils.plugins import get_plugins
from cms.templatetags.cms_tags import _get_placeholder

class AnchorPluginMenuModifier(Modifier):
    """

    """
    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        # if the menu is not yet cut, don't do anything
        if post_cut:
            return nodes
        # otherwise loop over the nodes        
        newnodes = []
        for node in nodes:
            try: 
                if "is_page" in node.attr and node.attr["is_page"]:

                    page_obj = Page.objects.get(id=node.id)                    
                    template_context = {
                        "request" : request,
                    }
                    placeholder_name = "content"

                    placeholder = _get_placeholder(request.current_page, page_obj,
                        template_context, placeholder_name)  # placeholder_name is a string
                    plugins = get_plugins(request, placeholder, page_obj.get_template())


                    for plugin in plugins:
                        if type(plugin).__name__ == "AnchorPluginModel":
                            newnode = NavigationNode(
                                plugin.anchor_menutitle,
                                node.url+"#"+plugin.anchor_name,
                                "{}-{}".format(page_obj.id,plugin.id),
                                node
                            )
                            newnode.parent_id = node.id
                            newnodes.append(newnode)
                            setattr(newnode, "selected", False)
                            node.children.append(newnode)                                       
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                # client.captureException()

        return nodes

menu_pool.register_modifier(AnchorPluginMenuModifier)
```

The code lives in cms_menus.py file.